Here map with React update data from props
I have an issue with refreshing data on the map. When I get new data, the old one stays on the map as well. I pass data as props from parent component to the  component.
I use React and 'HARP' engine.
I'll provide some of the code

Initialize Map Behavior:
new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map.current))

Prepare  Coordinates:


const vCoordinates = vData.map((data: myCustomType) => ({
  lat: data.telemetry.latitude,
  lng: data.telemetry.longitude,
  data,
  type: 'v'
}))

const cLocationsCoordinates = cLocations.map((data: myCustomType2) => ({
  lat: data.location.latitude,
  lng: data.location.longitude,
  data,
  type: 'c'
}))


Combine Coordinates:
const coordinates = [...vCoordinates, ...cLocationsCoordinates]

Create Data Points for Clustering
const dataPoints = coordinates.map((coord) => new H.clustering.DataPoint(coord.lat, coord.lng, 1, coord))

Create Clustering Provider


const clusteredDataProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(dataPoints, {
  clusteringOptions: {
    eps: CLUSTERING_OPTIONS.eps,
    minWeight: CLUSTERING_OPTIONS.minWeight
  },
  theme: {
    getClusterPresentation: (cluster) => {
      const clusterSize = cluster.getWeight()
      const clusterIcon = createClusterIcon(clusterSize)
      const clusterMarker = new H.map.Marker(cluster.getPosition(), {
        icon: clusterIcon,
        min: cluster.getMinZoom(),
        max: cluster.getMaxZoom(),
        data: cluster
      })
      return clusterMarker
    },
    getNoisePresentation: (noisePoint) => {
      const data = noisePoint.getData()
      const icon = data.type === 'v' ? vIcon : cIcon
      const marker = new H.map.Marker(noisePoint.getPosition(), {
        min: noisePoint.getMinZoom(),
        icon,
        data
      })

      return marker
    }
  }
})


Add Clustering Layer to Map
const layer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusteredDataProvider) map.current.addLayer(layer)

I've tried to apply removeObjects  and removeLayer map.current.removeObjects(map.current.getObjects())
and
const layers = map.current.getLayers() Object.keys(layers).forEach((key) => { map.current.removeLayer(layers[key]) }) 
But I had no luck with it.
How can I refresh data on the map without re-rendering  component?
